# How to Render Message Threads to Template in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to render a user's direct messages and group them into threads in the template. Each message has a "thread" field to indicate the thread. How would I render the messages to the template, grouped into their thread? Here is my model:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    transaction = models.OneToOneField(
        Transaction,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name='reciever',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I need to use [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) in the template.